# Convert SQL to linq to SQL with cross apply

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

Any idea how to convert this cross apply SQL query to linq-to-sql?

```
    select *
    from dbo.Company
    inner join dbo.Contact c on c.contID = dbo.Company.compContactID or dbo.Company.compContactID is null
    inner join dbo.Company_Program cp on cp.compID = dbo.Company.compID or dbo.Company.compID is null
    inner join dbo.Program p on cp.progID = p.progProgramID
    inner join dbo.Division d on d.divID = p.progDivisionID
    inner join dbo.PhoneType pt on pt.phtPhoneTypeID = c.contPhoneTypeID or c.contPhoneTypeID is null
    inner join dbo.PhoneNumber ph on ph.phoneID = pt.phtPhoneID or pt.phtPhoneID is null

    cross apply (select top 1*
        from dbo.Participation p
        where p.participationID = dbo.Company.compParticipationID or dbo.Company.compParticipationID is null 
    )  part 
    where divID = 29
```

Answer (score 2):

`CROSS APPLY` will evaluate the given query to each left hand side row, returning the first participation for the company, if one or more exist, or the first Participation in the table, if no company participations exist at all.

Ignoring the other tables for now, you should be able to achieve the same result as the original Sql `CROSS APPLY` with a projection which applies the same logic as above:

```
var result = db.Companies
    // Include / Join on the other tables here ...
    .Select(c => new 
     {
        Company = c,
        Participation = db.Partipations
             .FirstOrDefault(p => c.compParticipationID == p.participationID 
                                 || c.compParticipationID == null)
    })
   // Project out your final columns from Company, Participation etc.;
```

The above Linq however will exhibit the 1:N performance issue (i.e. a lookup in `Participations` for each row of `Company`). There are some performance optimizations to be had, e.g. if many of the companies don't have Participations (i.e. null compParticipationID) you could pre-fetch the first participation in the table and apply it in a coalesce:

```
var defaultParticipation = db.Partipations.FirstOrDefault();

// ... as above

    Participation = db.Partipations
         .FirstOrDefault(p => c.compParticipationID == p.participationID)
         ?? defaultParticipation;
```

Similarly if there are only a few `Participations` in the table, you could prefetch all of them and key them in a dictionary by `participationID`, and again coalescing to the default participation if the lookup fails (via `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey`).

Comment: I must also say that the `select top 1 * FROM Participation` in the original Sql query is disturbing - it could return a pseudo-random row since there is no `order by` or other predicate. In fact it might be a bug in the Sql, as it seems to have used the same 'default' pattern used in the other table joins?